# FusedLocationApi is not working while scheduling it with JobScheduler

Tags: android, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation, android-jobscheduler

Calling FusedLocationApi within jobscheduler doesn't work. I have tried in 2 ways but onConnected() are never called in both of them. How can I make it work? Thankyou

MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnStartJob = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startjob);

        jobScheduler = (JobScheduler)getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        btnStartJob.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ComponentName jobService =
                        new ComponentName(getPackageName(), MyJobService.class.getName());
                PersistableBundle bundle = new PersistableBundle();
                bundle.putString("lat", latitude+"");
                bundle.putString("lon", longitude+"");

                JobInfo jobInfo =
                        new JobInfo.Builder(MYJOBID, jobService).setPeriodic(10000).
                        setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY).
                        setRequiresCharging(false).
                        setRequiresDeviceIdle(false).
                        setPersisted(true).
                        setExtras(bundle).
                        build();

                int jobId = jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
                if(jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo)>0){
                }else{
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Try 1:

Here I have implemented ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener in JobService but its onConnected() method is never called...

```
public class MyJobService extends JobService implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {
    protected JobParameters mJobParameters;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    public MyJobService() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        Log.e("token", "Start Job Called");
        setUpLocationClientIfNeeded();
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        // Use high accuracy
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "MyJobService.onStopJob()",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(this.mGoogleApiClient,
                mLocationRequest, this); // This is the changed line.
        Log.e("onConnected", "onConnected");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    private void setUpLocationClientIfNeeded()
    {
        if(mGoogleApiClient == null)
            buildGoogleApiClient();
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        this.mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        this.mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.e("token",location.getLatitude()+""+location.getLongitude());
    }
}
```

Try 2:

Called innerClass that implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener in onStartJob of JobService but still onConnected method is never called

```
public class MyJobService extends JobService {
    private Location mLastLocation;
    String latitude = null;
    String longitude = null;
    protected JobParameters mJobParameters;

    private class GetLocation extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Integer> implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
        protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... jobID) {
            if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getBaseContext())
                        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                        .build();
            }
            return jobID[0];
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Integer jobID) {
            //h2 = new Handler();
            //Runnable run = new Runnable() {
            //   @Override
            //    public void run() {
            //        long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - 0;
            //        int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
            //        int minutes = seconds / 60;
            //        seconds     = seconds % 60;
            //        Log.i("JobSchedulerTest","Job Finished!");
            //       h2.postDelayed(this, 1500);

                    jobFinished(mJobParameters, true);
                }
            };


        }

        @Override
        public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

            Log.e("onConnected " , "onConnected" );
            createLocationRequest();
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        }

    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MyJobService.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MyJobService.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(final LocationResult locationResult) {
                latitude = locationResult.getLastLocation().getLatitude() + "";
                longitude = locationResult.getLastLocation().getLongitude() + "";
                Log.e("onLocationResult lat", latitude);
                Log.e("onLocationResult Lon", longitude);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLocationAvailability(LocationAvailability locationAvailability) {
            }
        }, null);
    }
    }


    public MyJobService() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        Log.d("onstart", "onStartJob() :: ");

        mJobParameters=jobParameters;
        Integer i=new Integer(jobParameters.getJobId());
        new GetLocation().execute(i);

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "MyJobService.onStopJob()",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have the location permission?

Comment: yeahh...     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

Comment: but do you have it? The user must grant the permission

Comment: no... I ran it in device and no permission is asked

Comment: well you have to ask for it in the code

Comment: @AmritaStha Did you get it working properly?